# How to open new tabs in background using extensions api?

Tags: javascript

How to make so that any new tabs from window where `location = "http://example.com/*"` were opened in background using chrome.tabs api? If all requests are from the same domain (not cross-origin).

I don't need any extensions, only code is need.

Comment: what did you tried until now?

Comment: I only have this to open only a certain link. But I need for any links in any time.
`chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.stackoverflow.com", active: false })`